# Can we show that $(E\times \mathbb R)^*=E^* \times \mathbb R$ where $E$ is a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, duality-theorems

Can we show $(E \oplus \mathbb R)^* \cong E^* \oplus \mathbb R$, where $E$ is a Banach space and $E^*$ is the dual space of $E$? What if $E$ is just a normed space or even a topological space?

To be specific, if $\Lambda$ is a linear functional on $(E \oplus \mathbb R)^*$, can we find a linear functional $\lambda$ on $E$ and a real number $k \in \mathbb R$ so that, for any $x\in E$ and $y\in\mathbb R$, 
$$\Lambda(x,y) = \lambda(x) + ky$$

Moreover, can we show $(E \oplus F)^* \cong E^* \oplus F^*$ where $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces?

Comment: Look at $\Phi:E^*\oplus F^* \to (E\oplus F)^*$ defined by $\Phi(x^*,y^*)(x,y)=x^*(x)+y^*(y)$.

Comment: I am just beginning to learn functional analysis. I find it hard to write down a rigorous proof. Can I find this result in some reference books?